# Using LinkSnooper for monitoring the communication with an installable MathLink program

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

How can I monitor the communication between an [installable MathLink program](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/InstallableMathLinkPrograms.html) and the kernel?  Can [LinkSnooper](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v8/JLink/ref/java/com/wolfram/jlink/util/LinkSnooper.html) do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let me present an alternative approach. The whole commandline work and link naming and connecting can be simplified. What we need is the location of the LinkSnooper program and the location of your *MathLink* program and then you can set up everything in exactly **one** call to `Install` from *Mathematica*.

I have tried to make the following, where I demonstrate it with the `addtwo` *MathLink* example, as general as possible and it hopefully works on all operating systems.

**Remark:** In the following we will work with paths which probably contain evil characters like spaces which need a correct quoting. If something goes wrong, please check this first!

Unfortunately, a Java VM is not provided by Wolfram for all systems. You have to ensure, that `java` is found. First, let's build the call for `Install`

```
cmdline = StringJoin[
 "java -cp ",
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "JLink", "JLink.jar"}],
 " com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname '",
 FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "MathLink",
  "DeveloperKit", $SystemID, "PrebuiltExamples", "addtwo"}],
 "'"
]
```

On my machine this gives

```
java -cp /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar 
com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname 
'/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/9.0/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/\
 Linux-x86-64/PrebuiltExamples/addtwo'
```

As you can see, the call to the LinkSnooper is equivalent to the one in Szabolcs answer, but we let LinkSnooper start our *MathLink* program directly.

The good thing is, that we are finished at this point. Just use

```
link = Install[cmdline]
```

and the LinkSnooper pops up with all the traffic between you and the `addtwo` program.

[image]

Comment: Can you test this on OS X?  LinkSnooper launches fine but then the `Install` simply hangs here.  It prints on up to (but not including) `Start Monitoring...`  I verified the paths to `addtwo` and it is correct (pasting it to a terminal starts it).

Comment: @Szabolcs I did test it. That's why I had to edit the post and simplify the java-executable, because on OSX they don't come with Mathematica. I tried it on my retina-MB and on my MacPro in the office.

Comment: Does [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s135/sh/343b5c2f-882a-41a3-9f68-35dd128a70cc/e43fb92cf028cc5ff5a7b2bec8f37ded/res/c0bce673-802c-4c4d-adf4-373c16201b51/skitch.png) look okay to you?  Do you see any difference from what you get, e.g. in the command line options listed by LinkSnooper?  At this point `Install` just hangs ...

Comment: Never mind, it was a quoting issue.  I need to change all spaces in the `-kernelname` to escaped spaces.  (I have `Mathematica.app` renamed to `Mathematica 9.app` here)

Comment: Ahh, the bad spaces in filenames..

Comment: Note the  LinkSnooper is a built-in tool in 11.1 [here](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/27/58d8f9ef14d02.jpg)

Answer (score 10):

LinkSnooper is a great tool any time you need to see what's traveling across a link. You can actually get it completely set up to monitor an installable MathLink program in a single `Install` command.

The syntax for `Install` is

```
Install["path to .exe"]
```

When using LinkSnooper, it is not the .exe that you want to launch directly, but rather LinkSnooper as the intermediary. So this becomes

```
Install["command line to launch Java, with LinkSnooper as the main class, 
      passing LinkSnooper the path to the exe to launch via the kernelname parameter"]
```

This example, for Windows, uses " to quote all embedded paths. On other platforms you might have to use ' instead.

```
Install["java -cp \"" <> 
         FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "Links", "JLink", "JLink.jar"}] <>
         "\" com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname \"path/to/installable/exe\""]
```

Comment: Great, halirutan beat me by 20 minutes! Plus, he said it better.

Answer (score 5):

Here are step by step instructions.  In the below commands change `$InstallationDirectory` to the Mathematica install location on your system.

First launch LinkSnooper from the command line like this:

```
java -cp $InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Links/JLink/JLink.jar com.wolfram.jlink.util.LinkSnooper -kernelname klink -kernelmode listen
```

Be sure to quote paths with spaces properly.  Here `klink` is the name of the `Kernel <-> LinkSnooper` link.

LinkSnooper will prompt you for the name of `LinkSnooper <-> program` link.  Type `plink`, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now connect to `klink` in Mathematica using

```
link = LinkConnect["klink"]
```

Connect to `plink` by launching the MathLink program, skipping on the `Create link:` prompt (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and typing `plink` at the `Connect to link:` prompt.

Now "install" the program into the kernel using the

```
Install[link]
```

command, and watch what's happening in the LinkSnooper console.

Comment: `LinkSnooping`? Just curious, what are you connecting too?

Comment: @ruebenko My own program.  It was not completely clear how to handle `Manual` argument passing and `Manual` return in installable programs (e.g. do I need to `MLPutSymbol(stdlink, "Null")` if I don't want to return anything? Or can I just not write anything to the link?)  As far as I understand, if I want to get a `Real64Array`, I must use `Manual` argument passing.  The templates (`.tm` files) seem to only support `RealList`, not n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @ruebenko We're trying to build a MATLABLink with rm-rf, see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18366/12) and [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7278/mengine-on-os-x)

Comment: I don't know the answer to those questions but I'll try to find out. Concernig the MATLABLink, sounds like a big project. Good luck with it!

Comment: Note the  LinkSnooper is a built-in tool in 11.1 [here](https://ooo.0o0.ooo/2017/03/27/58d8f9ef14d02.jpg)