# Detect front-end Abort in C WSTP process

Tags: abort, mathlink-or-wstp

I have a long loop in a C WSTP process, within which I intermittently check for abort messages sent by the front-end:

```
void checkIfUserAborted() {
  
    if (WSMessageReady(stdlink)) {

        int code, arg;
        WSGetMessage(stdlink, &code, &arg);

        if (code == WSTerminateMessage || code == WSInterruptMessage || 
            code == WSAbortMessage     || code == WSImDyingMessage) {
                
            // throw error
        }
    }
}
```

```
void myWSTPFunc() {

    try {

        for (big loop) {

            checkIfUserAborted();

            // do task
        }

    } catch ... {

        // handle abort
    }
}
```

This code was adapted from [this](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf) great but very outdated doc, which uses the defunct [`MLAbort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSAbort.html) (for which the replacement [`WSAbort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSAbort.html) somehow went missing). This code previously worked in version 11 of Mathematica on MacOS, allowing me to detect and handle the abort during `myWSTPFunc()`, as invoked by the user clicking `Evaluation > Abort Evaluation` in their notebook.

As of Mathematica v13 however, this process no longer works. Invoking `Evaluation > Abort Evaluation` no longer triggers a `WSAbortMessage` discoverable by `checkIfUserAborted()`.

I managed to get LinkSnooper working as per [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18719/using-linksnooper-for-monitoring-the-communication-with-an-installable-mathlink#), but all it logs during my abort invocation is

```
****** Message FE ---> K:  on Main: 3
```

I hence have two questions:

- How can I use LinkSnooper to see the specific message my Abort induced?
- Is there an updated way to listen for aborts in WSTP? Is [`LinkInterrupt`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinkInterrupt.html) relevant?

Comment: Can you show a complete minimal example where checking `MLAbort` does not work?

Comment: `ML`-named functions are not "defunct". They work fine, and should be completely equivalent to the `WS`-ones. If there is any difference whatsoever, it's a bug and you should report it to Wolfram.

Comment: @Szabolcs `MLAbort` is undefined, and `WSAbort` is undeclared. It doesn't get more defunct than that.

Comment: `MLAbort` works perfectly fine here.

Comment: Can you show a complete minimal example that demonstrates that MLAbort and WSAbort do not work?

Comment: The MWE is `#include "wstp.h"` and making any reference to either `MLAbort` or `WSAbort` (causing an undefined compile error). I'm using the 2017 Linux/MacOS `wstp.h`, and the 2019 Windows `wstp.h`. What year are you using?

Comment: I looked into how this works and wrote an answer. There are still several details that are unclear to me such as when one should use `MLGetMessage` directly vs using a message handler. I am curious what your application is given that you are writing your own main loop.

Answer (score 3):

I looked into this and it seems that there are two situations we need to distinguish: writing an installable MathLink program or setting up the communication loop manually.

First, `ML` and `WS` functions should behave equivalently, you just need to make sure that you consistently stick to either the ML versions or the WS versions throughout your program. In this answer I will use the ML names.

#### Installable MathLink program

`MLAbort` is only available when you are writing an [installable MathLink program](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/SettingUpExternalFunctionsToBeCalledFromTheWolframLanguage.html). In this case you will have a `.tm` template file which is translated to C code with `mprep`. It is in the output of `mprep` that `MLAbort` is *defined* (although it is *declared* in `mathlink.h`). This code needs to be compiled and linked into your executable, otherwise you will see a linker error that `MLAbort` is not found.

#### Manual communication

If you are writing your own main loop to communicate through a MathLink connection, you can emulate what is done in installable MathLink programs, and set up your own `MLAbort`. It seems that this is done by setting up a message handler, like so:

```c
int MLAbort = 0;

...

void MLDefaultHandler( MLINK mlp, int message, int n)
{
    switch (message){
    case MLTerminateMessage:
        MLDone = 1;
    case MLInterruptMessage:
    case MLAbortMessage:
        MLAbort = 1;
    default:
        return;
    }
}
```

Then the message handler is registered using `MLSetMessageHandler(mlp, MLDefaultHandler);`

I am *assuming* that the message handler will be called from a parallel thread, thus in your main code you will be able to simply use `if (MLAbort) ...` as usual, without needing to worry about `MLAbort` getting updated in a timely manner.

Note that the above code was copied directly from the source file generated by `mprep` and contains other details not relevant to the question such as `MLDone`.

If you set up your own communication loop, it would be a good idea to look carefully at how this works in installable MathLink programs (the output of `mprep`) as the documentation is rather sparse on this. So far I have not had the need to do this.

Comment: I am creating an installable ML program using a template file compiled with `mprep`, and I am *not* writing my own main loop. The project is [QuESTlink](https://github.com/QTechTheory/QuESTlink) and my message-checking workaround to the undefined `MLAbort` is viewable [here](https://github.com/QTechTheory/QuESTlink/blob/398db6543a908c763db23a9fd09b82f0831aabdc/Link/errors.cpp#L105), though which no longer works. What OS and Mathematica version provide your `mprep` and `wstp.h`?

Comment: (I can also confirm that the C file output by `mprep` of the templates file contains no definitions of either `MLAbort` nor `WSAbort`)