# Export to mat file does not work

Tags: export, version-7, matlab

I use this command from the *Mathematica* documentation center

```
Export["1.mat", {"t" -> {{1,2,3}},"u" -> {{4,5,6}}}, "LabeledData"]
```

to save data as mat file with two variables `t` and `u`, and it does not work. The file is empty! The command `Export["1.mat",{{1,2,3}}]` works fine. How to solve this problem? I'd like to save in single file plenty variables.  I am using Mathematica 7.

Comment: With version 9 it works correctly.  I cannot test with version 7.

Comment: If you don't have access to any more recent versions of Mathematica, and v7 won't export correctly, you can try using some Mathematica-MATLAB interface (e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica/18366#18366)) to transfer the data.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try to install M9.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only export data in the form of matrices in version 7. If you want to store multiple pieces of data x and y, you can do something like this:

```
x = {1, 2, 3};
y = {4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
z = PadRight[{x, y}];
Export["testz.mat", z]
```

In Matlab, you will have one thing, called "Expression1" that consists of the matrix z. You will have to unpack it yourself over in Matlab to use x and y separately again.

Comment: Are you a MATLAB user too?

Comment: Matlab is my native tongue...

Comment: Szabolcs -- I just saw your post about mEngine http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica/18366#18366 -- I had no idea that such a thing existed. It sounds like a great resource...