# Schwarz-Christoffel toolbox

Tags: plotting, packages, complex, parametric-functions

Is there a toolbox for working with Schwarz-Christoffel transformations in *Mathematica*? More generally, is there a toolbox for visualizing conformal mappings in the complex plane?

There are a lot of operations (plotting how regions and curves are transformed, calculating derivatives, etc.) which are not very complicated to implement, but are pretty verbose and I would prefer having a ready-made set of functions that handles that.

Comment: I don't believe there's one as extensive as [the one in MATLAB](http://www.math.udel.edu/~driscoll/SC); if desperate, there's [MATLink](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10231). ([Here](http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~dgcrowdy/SKPrime) is a related MATLAB routine that may be of interest.)

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the tag addition, but I really liked how my former tags formed a sentence

Comment: [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConformalMapping.html) has a notebook on conformal mappings. I also believe that one of Trott's *Mathematica* guidebooks has a section on them. Also, the demonstrations site has quite a few examples.

Comment: If you find one, consider adding it to http://packagedata.net/