# how to import a matlab 3 dimensional array into mathematica

Tags: import, matlab

I have created a three dimensional array "data" in matlab by using the following commands :

```
data=100*ones(100,100,100);
data(10:20,10:20,10:20)=20;
data(80:90,80:90,80:90)=80;
save data;
```

As you can see, most of elements in "data" have the value 100, but there are two zones located at two corners with value 20 and 80 respectively. Then I created a graph to show these two zones. Using the "isosurface" function in matlab, I get the picture below 
[image]

Now I want to import the "data" into mma, and plot a similar graph in mma. I tried the following commands in mma but got some errors :[image]

what's the mistake ? how should i do?
thanks for reviewing the navie quetions  : )

Comment: Have you seen this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24478/5

Comment: Please show precisely what you tried so far.  I don't see any problems when importing a mat file generated this way.

Comment: (Just use `Import`)

Comment: It's a good idea to look at the structure of the expression that `Import` returns.  What I get is a list containing a path (string) and a 3D array.  I need to take the second element of the list to get the 3D array.  From the error message in your post it looks like you have a list containing a single 3D array.  Take the first element of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Your "data" has most values 100 with some 80s and some 20s, yet your imported array from data.mat is almost all 1's. Once you locate the correct data file, you can check that

```
Dimensions[a]
{1,100,100,100}
```

has the wrong format for 3D plotting. You can fix this with Flatten, and then:

```
ListPlot3D[Flatten[a, 1]]
```

[image]