# Matlab to Mathematica conversion

Tags: matlab

Is there a list of corresponding commands between *Mathematica* and Matlab, including `Solve`, `NSolve`, `DSolve`, `NDSolve` and `Plot` in particular?

#### Edit

May I seek your indulgence as there is a possibility of  'Mathematicaizing' the following surfaces in Matlab in a possibly long Brander thread. We have the author's permission as he states these are in the public domain.

Starting with the simplest we could visualize a plethora of surfaces that   appear to be more complicated than the Kuen or Breather. Mathematics of Frontals and Mathematica adaptation could be addressed together.

So I request for continuance or a new one with reference to this one.

[K_neg_Brander_DK](http://davidbrander.org/Ksurf_tutorial.pdf)

[Shape software](http://davidbrander.org/software.html)

Comment: I don't know it there is such a resource but even if there were, I strongly doubt its usefulness. Especially if you went from Matlab to Mathematica you will really benefit from the consistent naming scheme and documentation in Mathematica so I don't see the point in having a "cheat sheet". Can you elaborate on your intended use?

Comment: I think that even with high level functions (not basic programming constructs), it is not a good idea to *think it MATLAB* and *just use a dictionary to translate to Mathematica*.  They're different enough that this won't result in very good Mathematica problem solving.  But it is still good to look at how the same problem can be solve with one or the other.  [Nasser has a webpage like this.](http://12000.org/my_notes/mma_matlab_control/index.htm)  There might be others too.

Comment: Well, there is really no equivalence in terms of `NDSolve` for example. In MATLAB you have to choose the method and any parameters (`NDSolve` tries to choose it for you) and interpolate the result to recover the solution. But at least the functionality can be duplicated. For `Solve`, `DSolve`, and `NSolve`, I don't think this is the case. They all work with symbolic (or hybrid symbolic-numeric) methods that MATLAB simply doesn't have. Nasser's collection of examples seems like an excellent resource.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it embodies the assumption that there are "corresponding commands" in MATLAB and *Mathematica*, whereas in fact the general approach to problem solving is quite different, and for many commands there is no real correspondence. Thus, I think that this cannot be answered productively without reference to specific problems. The rationale is explained further [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/).

Comment: Yes, please close it. I am getting into the thick of it now again. At first I was on Matlab, then changed and stuck to Mathematica ever since. What prompted me for the question was the work  to put in if one needs to use an available good program in Matlab ! Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: Then this seems related: [Calling MATLAB from Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10231/)

Comment: Fine, thanks for it.

Comment: I would love to take a few days and devote them to making those plots in *Mathematica*, but yeah, this isn't a suitable question for this site, at least the way it's written

Comment: I am trying to  see common interest here . We could close this and start  anew another thread, it is a tall order for a single interested individual's time or effort.  Please feel free to suggest its activity title,scope,  bits of organization needed etc. for re-casting it.

Comment: @Narasimham, I think it needs to be approached not from the point of view of how to convert Matlab code to Mathematica, but from the perspective of "how do I realize these equations into the form of mathematica input".  And even there, in small, realizable steps where you make an effort to do the first step and then ask for improvements or incremental help when you are stuck.  **Then** it's in the scope of this site

Comment: There not on the same page but this should be similar to what you are talking about http://hyperpolyglot.org/computer-algebra http://hyperpolyglot.org/numerical-analysis  Hyperpolyglot classifies them differently and doesn't include everything by any means.

Comment: @JasonB (first part) You mean code it directly afresh into Mathematica.

Comment: Mathematica to Matlab: http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/577/