# open Matlab sheet and plot

Tags: plotting, import, matlab

I have managed to import my data into mathematica, but I can't find a way to show the plot the way it was in the lab (Matlab automatically generated file usually show me a graph). Is there a way Mathematica can tell what is in the file and show the graph the way it was in Matlab. Every command (for Matlab) is in the file already.

```
%********************************************
clear
M=[
% Frequence       Amplitude       Phase
10      9.359000E+0     1.340000E+0;
11      9.341000E+0     320.000000E-3;
13      9.418000E+0     10.000000E-3;
14      9.405000E+0     -90.000000E-3;
16      9.410000E+0     -70.000000E-3;
18      9.408000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
20      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
22      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
25      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
28      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
32      9.406000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
35      9.407000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
40      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
45      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
50      9.406000E+0     -40.000000E-3;



];
figure (1);
semilogx(M(:,1),M(:,2));
grid;
title('Amplitude et Phase');
xlabel('Frequence en Hz');
ylabel('Amplitude en dB');
```

of course i skimmed the data but this is my Matlab code.

```
% second plot
figure (2);

title('Amplitude et Phase');
semilogx(M(:,1),M(:,3));
grid;
xlabel('Frequence en Hz');
ylabel('Phase en degre');
```

Comment: The commands and syntax in *Mathematica* are different from those found in Matlab, so your code will not work as you have presented it. See the documentation for `ListLogLinearPlot`, which is *Mathematica*'s version of `semilogx` for sampled data. See also `List` if you're unfamiliar with how to format your data for use in `ListLogLinearPlot`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see why one would expect that two so dissimilar program languages with a completely different syntax and philosophy like MatLAB and Mathematica could use each others programs.

To get your plot you really have to code in Mathematica (or Wolfram Language, as we're supposed to call it nowadays):

First, I copy the data as a string and let it interpret as a table, after removing the semicolons at the end of the lines:

```
m =
 ImportString[
  StringReplace["10      9.359000E+0     1.340000E+0;
   11      9.341000E+0     320.000000E-3;
   13      9.418000E+0     10.000000E-3;
   14      9.405000E+0     -90.000000E-3;
   16      9.410000E+0     -70.000000E-3;
   18      9.408000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
   20      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
   22      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
   25      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
   28      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
   32      9.406000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
   35      9.407000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
   40      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
   45      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
   50      9.406000E+0     -40.000000E-3;", ";" -> ""], "Table"]
```

Then the plot itself:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[m[[All, {1, 2}]],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequence en Hz", "Amplitude en dB", "", ""},
 PlotLabel -> "Amplitude et Phase",
 PlotRange->All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The second plot, with a few options added to draw connecting lines:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[m[[All, {1, 3}]],
 Frame -> True,
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequence en Hz", "Phase en degre", "", ""},
 PlotLabel -> "Amplitude et Phase",
 PlotRange -> All,
 Joined -> True,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck with the data and had difficulty finding a way to modify it. I tried 'Rest[]' function, but couldn't make it to work. Now I understand your trick with Table formatting to.Thnks.

Comment: "Wolfram Language" is only true for V10: "[*Mathematica 10* is the first version of *Mathematica* based on the complete Wolfram Language.](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/?source=frontpage-features)"

Answer (score 6):

Another way is to use the [MATLink](http://matlink.org) package (see [Calling MATLAB from Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10231/calling-matlab-from-mathematica/24478#24478)), if you have Matlab installed.

```
(* See http://matlink.org for installation *)
Needs["MATLink`"];
OpenMATLAB[]

test = MScript["test",
  "
  %********************************************
  clear
  M=[
  % Frequence       Amplitude       Phase
  10      9.359000E+0     1.340000E+0;
  11      9.341000E+0     320.000000E-3;
  13      9.418000E+0     10.000000E-3;
  14      9.405000E+0     -90.000000E-3;
  16      9.410000E+0     -70.000000E-3;
  18      9.408000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
  20      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
  22      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
  25      9.407000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
  28      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
  32      9.406000E+0     -60.000000E-3;
  35      9.407000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
  40      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
  45      9.405000E+0     -50.000000E-3;
  50      9.406000E+0     -40.000000E-3;



  ];",
  "Overwrite" -> True]

MScript["test"]

MEvaluate@test

m = MGet["M"]  (* this retrieves the matrix M *)
(*
  {{10., 9.359, 1.34}, {11., 9.341, 0.32}, {13., 9.418, 0.01}, {14., 
    9.405, -0.09}, {16., 9.41, -0.07}, {18., 9.408, -0.06}, {20., 
    9.407, -0.06}, {22., 9.407, -0.06}, {25., 9.407, -0.06}, {28., 
    9.405, -0.05}, {32., 9.406, -0.06}, {35., 9.407, -0.05}, {40., 
    9.405, -0.05}, {45., 9.405, -0.05}, {50., 9.406, -0.04}}
*)

ListLogLinearPlot[m[[All, 1 ;; 2]], Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All,
 PlotLabel -> "Amplitude et Phase",
 Frame -> True, GridLines -> All,
 FrameLabel -> {"Frequence en Hz", "Amplitude en dB"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Similarly for the other plot:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[m[[All, {1, 3}]],...]
```