# Mathematica's Singular Value Decomposition different from another math engine

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, matlab

I’ve been working with SVD – singular value decomposition. Things weren’t working as expected. Thus, I looked over to Matlab and executed the following code:

```
X=[105 103 103 66;245 227 242 267;685 803 750 586; 147 160 122 93; 193 235 184 209; 156 175 147 139; 720 874 566 1033; 253 265 171 143; 488 570 418 355; 198 203 220 187; 360 365 337 334; 1102 1137 957 674; 1472 1582 1462 1494; 57 73 53 47; 1374 1256 1572 1506;
375 475 458 135; 54 64 62 41];
data = X; [M,N] = size(data);
mn = mean(data,2); 
data = data - repmat(mn,1,N); 
Y = data' / sqrt(N-1); 
[u,S,PC] = svd(Y);
S=diag(S);V=S.*S;
signals=PC'*data;
```

It results in a sensible PCA diagram for the data. Now, if I run it in Mathematica

```
countrydata = {{105, 103, 103, 66}, {245, 227, 242, 267}, {685, 803, 
750, 586}, {147, 160, 122, 93}, {193, 235, 184, 209}, {156, 175, 
147, 139}, {720, 874, 566, 1033}, {253, 265, 171, 143}, {488, 570,
 418, 355}, {198, 203, 220, 187}, {360, 365, 337, 334}, {1102, 
1137, 957, 674}, {1472, 1582, 1462, 1494}, {57, 73, 53, 
47}, {1374, 1256, 1572, 1506}, {375, 475, 458, 135}, {54, 64, 62, 
41}};

datamean = {{Mean[countrydata[[1]]]}};


Print[datamean];

For[i = 2, i <= Dimensions[countrydata][[1]], i++,

datamean = Append[ datamean, {Mean[countrydata[[i]]]}]


];



datashift = countrydata;


For[i = 1, i <= Dimensions[countrydata][[1]], i++,

    For[j = 1, j <=  Dimensions[countrydata[[1]]][[1]], j++,

      datashift[[i]][[j]] = countrydata[[i]][[j]] - datamean[[i]][[1]];]];


Y = Transpose[datashift]/(Sqrt[(Dimensions[countrydata[[1]]][[1]]) - 1]);


svd = SingularValueDecomposition[N[Y, 100]];

S = Diagonal[svd[[2]]];


V = S*S;



signal = Transpose[-svd[[3]]].datashift;


Print[MatrixForm[N[Y, 10]]];

 Show[ListPlot[{{{signal[[1, 1]], 0}}, {{signal[[1, 2]], 
 0}}, {{signal[[1, 3]], 0}}, {{signal[[1, 4]], 0}}},
    PlotRange -> All,
    PlotLegends -> {"England", "Wales", "Scotland", "N. Ireland" },
    PlotLabel -> "First two principal components for  data",
    FrameLabel -> {"z1", "z2"},
    RotateLabel -> False,
    Axes -> False,
    Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}},
    ImageSize -> {300, 300}]]
```

I get the following information for the V matrix in the singular value decomposition. This is the PC matrix in Matlab and svd[[3]] in Mathematica. The other two matrices returned in Singular Value Decomposition svd[[1]] and svd[[2]] exactly match mathematica.

Matlab PC: 
-0.0569553797856850
0.0479276281346853
-0.258916658336122
-0.0844149825250836
-0.00519362266004777
-0.0376209828394020
0.401402060296248
-0.151849941562302
-0.243593728990274
-0.0268862325367470
-0.0364882691115938
-0.632640897872237
-0.0477028583736490
-0.0261877559085335
0.232244140472894
-0.463968167976707
-0.0296502010879939

Mathematica svd[[3]]:
0.05695537979
-0.04792762813
0.2589166583
0.08441498253
0.005193622660
0.03762098284
-0.4014020603
0.1518499416
0.2435937290
0.02688623254
0.03648826911
0.6326408979
0.04770285837
0.02618775591
-0.2322441405
0.4639681680
0.02965020109

This is all and well. It matches - apart from the sign. Now, if we go to the 4th column

Matlab gives: 
-0.400748417916043
-0.150602373645460
-0.676298033445679
-0.0733743113594902
0.165183462293022
0.0375841868716541
-0.150666145597042
-0.103524165890781
0.124583909064645
0.0312459639649717
-0.0235673440745193
-0.150688757752460
0.322911600549900
0.0339945596788104
-0.148559469028165
0.351916694927059
0.0271722903782781

Mathematica gives: 
-0.9979609973
-0.0009722258735
0.001277619728
0.004860699968
-0.004240772408
0.0005876914821
-0.03923679062
0.01152344604
0.008614386639
0.0005409596602
0.002511166093
0.04306340746
-0.009183918074
-0.00001644119820
-0.008341374583
0.01635552490
0.0005560180332

Which is massively different. This trend continues for the rest of the lines. Why does there exist this disparity between the two Math Engines?

I thought it might be something to do with the domain matrices and U and V in the singular value decomposition are not unique, so it is difficult to compare results from different math engines. From another stack overflow post. But, this wouldn't explain the massive differences - or the similarity in the first few columns.

**Note, the graphs returned are the same. Just the svd[[3]] and PC matrices are different.**

Matlab reference for SVD: http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html
Based on tutorial for PCA: http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~szalay/class/2015/SignalProcPCA.pdf

Comment: It is because $Y^* Y$ has three non-zero eigenvalues and the rest are zero; columns 4 through 17 of PC form an orthonormal basis for the null space.  There are infinitely many ways to do that.  Given that the residual of the SVD, $U\Sigma V^* - Y$, is different in the two systems, I think the explanation is that they constructed bases in different ways, perhaps due to differences in round-off. I don't think there is a conventional standard method for completing a basis; I'm sure there is not a canonical one.

Comment: In support of what Michael E2 says in his comment: **1** Compare the approximation norms of the decompositions in both Matlab and Mathematica. E.g.  `Norm[svd[[1]].svd[[2]].Transpose[svd[[3]]] - Y]`. **2** Look at `TensorRank[Y]`. **3** How the results from the two systems compare with low rank SVD? E.g. `SingularValueDecomposition[Y, 3]`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematical one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. However, I admit I am relatively new and not quite understanding of the guidelines here. But, surely it is the math mathematica is using which is of interest here - not the math itself, which makes it a mathematica question? I plan on investigating the ideas Anton put forward and reporting back.Further, the solutions suggested could be the reason Mathematica gives different results to other math engines.

Comment: Tomi, I won't vote to close, not yet, so that I might see what you find. But with respect to @m_goldberg's comment, as I understand SVD, one cannot say whether Matlab's or Mathematica's construction of `PC`/`svd[[3]]` is better. I think that it doesn't matter and that the 4th-17th columns can be ignored. The question of what math is used by *Mathematica* does not seem interesting in this case. Further, since the norm of the residual is less in *Mathematica* than in Matlab, one might argue that in this particular case, *Mathematica's* way is better. But that argument is not terribly convincing.

Comment: FWIW, *Mathematica's* columns agree with `NullSpace`.  Try `NullSpace[N@Y] - Transpose[svd[[3]]][[4 ;; 17]]`.  One can also see that the 14 columns of Matlab's PC span the same space: `MatrixRank[
 Join[Transpose[svd[[3]]][[4 ;; 17]], Transpose[pc][[4 ;; 17]]]]`.  (See http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/24478 for importing Matlab computations into *Mathematica*.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 If you feel like making your comments an answer let me know.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks, I think the OP might get a better answer on datascience.SE or math.SE.  I think an answer in terms of PCA, instead of linear algebra (which is all I can give) or internal implementation details (which may be unavailable), might be more satisfactory.  So I don't think I would give an answer here.

Comment: @Tomi, try this to centralize your matrix: `countrydata // 
 Query[{Identity, Query[All, Mean]} /* 
   Replace[{mat_, mean_} :> Query[# - mean &][mat]]]`